# Powershell Runspaces Parallel script execution: Is Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption commandlet threadsafe?

Tags: .net, powershell, azure

When running the powershell commandlet: 
`Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption`

in parallel and separate runspaces, we are seeing transient/intermittent failures with stacktrace seen below. However, when we run this same commandlet serially, I've not seen this issue happen.

**Possible Reasons I've come up with so far:**

- Is it known that this commandlet is not thread-safe? (on purpose or bug?)
- Contention/locking on file `{ReleaseUser}\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell\ErrorRecords\Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption_YYYY-MM-DD-THH-MM-SS-PPP.log` where the commandlet seems to log information related to resolving a token (no actual errors in this file).

**Stack Trace for one of the scripts running this command:**

> [Exception:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n
>   at System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.OrderedDictionaryEnumerator.get_Value()\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.ClientFactory.GetCustomHandlers()\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.ClientFactory.CreateClient[TClient](AzureContext context, Endpoint endpoint)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.TransparentDataEncryption.Services.AzureSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryptionCommunicator.GetCurrentSqlClient(String clientRequestId)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.TransparentDataEncryption.Adapter.AzureSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryptionAdapter.GetTransparentDataEncryption(String resourceGroupName, String serverName, String databaseName)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.TransparentDataEncryption.Cmdlet.SetAzureSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption.GetEntity()\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Common.AzureSqlCmdletBase'2.ExecuteCmdlet()\r\n
>   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()]\

**Stack Trace For a second thread running the same commandlet:**

> Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", Source: "System", StackTrace: "   at System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.IndexOfKey(Object key)\r\n   at System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.set_Item(Object key, Object value)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Factories.ClientFactory.AddHandler[T](T handler)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.BeginProcessing()\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing()\r\n   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin()"`

**Suspicious**: both commands blow up when enumerating/accessing `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary` according to the stack-traces.

**Significance**: Are the two instances of the command accessing the **SAME** dictionary?

Comment: I've submitted this question to Microsoft's Powershell Azure GitHub account as well: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2580

Comment: Note that it appears Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase/New-AzureRmSqlDatabase have the same issue with concurrent execution.  They appear to edit the same instance of an ArrayList under the covers.  This information is provided verbatim - i have not confirmed this behavior by looking at the source code for these commandlets, I'm just assuming based on the exception I received.

Answer (score 3):

Will's answer seems to support our suspicion that this (and other) commandlets are not thread-safe. In order to deal with this, we "lock" around calling such commandlets using a mutex as the coordination mechanism.

Using this thread as inspiration, built a simple implementation of a process locking/coordination mechanism (using Mutexes) in powershell:

```
function Wait-OnMutex
{
    param(
    [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $MutexId
    )

    try
    {
        $MutexInstance = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex -ArgumentList 'false', $MutexId

        while (-not $MutexInstance.WaitOne(1000))
        {
            Start-Sleep -m 500;
        }

        return $MutexInstance
    } 
    catch [System.Threading.AbandonedMutexException] 
    {
        $MutexInstance = New-Object System.Threading.Mutex -ArgumentList 'false', $MutexId
        return Wait-OnMutex -MutexId $MutexId
    }

}

##
## example script calling unsafe commandlet
##

$MutexInstance = Wait-OnMutex -MutexId 'SomeMutexId12345'

## this is where you do work inside the "lock"
## call the commandlet needing to be single-threaded
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabaseTransparentDataEncryption -arg1 value

$MutexInstance.ReleaseMutex()
```

Hope This helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

@MSC,

> Is it known that this commandlet is not thread-safe? (on purpose or bug?)

**Reason:**
As far as I known, It depended on the Class Library whether is thread safe. From the source code(http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/ordereddictionary.cs,d02ab0d292f01b57 ),  we can see the function (`IndexOfKey(key)`). It is more related to `objectsArray`. We can see this object code as following:

```
   private ArrayList objectsArray {
            get {
                if (_objectsArray == null) {
                    _objectsArray = new ArrayList(_initialCapacity);
                }
                return _objectsArray;
            }
        }
```

It appeared that if we used the parallel threads to call this function, it will throw the exception. It wasn't locked.

**Howto:**

1. Use the lock mechanism to locked the '`objectArray`' in powershell
2. Use the single thread to call this function.

Hope that helps.